# Detecting valid field on cellEdit

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

this should be pretty easy just can't find the answer in the documentation. So I'm using [jQuery Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/validate) and creating an error message when a rule is broken. Easy enough.

```js
validationFailed:function(cell, value, validators){
    $('#data-errors').html('<span class="error error-message">....</span>')
},
```

I want to remove that error message once the error is fixed but I can't see how to do it. I assume there is a really simple callback that I could run in the `cellEdited` function, a `cellEdited` callback sort of thing, or validate the entire table like how other validate plugins work:

```js
    if($('#data-table').valid()){ ... }
```

I just can't find it in the documentation:)

Answer (score 0):

The ***cellEdited*** callback will be called if a cell passes validation and has been successfully edited.

You can either bind to this  for the table as a whole

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    cellEdited:function(cell){
        //cell - cell component
    },
});
```

or if you only want to monitor a specific column you can set it in a column definition:

```js
{title:"Name", field:"name", cellEdited:function(cell){
        //cell - cell component
    },
}
```